# xarray rechunk after shuffling data

Tags: tensorflow, python-xarray, netcdf

I am trying to use xarray with tensorflow. After the end of each epoch, the data is shuffled along the time dimension. The netcdf files have `(time,lat,lon,level)`. I use a chunk size of 1024 on the time dimension which has about 400k values. The problem I am having is that after the `DataArray` is shuffled, performance of the data pipeline drops significantly.

I have tried setting the chunk size and re-chunking after the data is shuffled but doesn't seem to help. On the other hand, if I write the shuffled data to disk and read it back again with a chunk size of 1024, it goes as fast as the un-shuffled data. So what am I missing with the re-chunk that made is slow compared to reading again from disk?

Here is the code I am using:

```
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        "Shuffle dataset at the end of epoch"
        if self.shuffle == True:
            # Get the Dask array containing the data values
            dask_data = self.data.data

            # Create a shuffled index array along the 'time' dimension
            shuffled_indices = da.random.permutation(
                dask_data.shape[0]
            )

            # Use Dask delayed computation to perform the shuffling
            shuffled_data = dask_data[shuffled_indices, :,  :, :]

            # shuffled_data = da.rechunk(shuffled_data, chunks={0: 1024})

            # Create a new DataArray with the shuffled data
            self.data = xr.DataArray(
                shuffled_data, coords=self.data.coords, dims=self.data.dims
            )
            self.data = self.data.chunk({"time": 1024})
    
            ## save data to file and read it agan
            #self.data.to_netcdf("save.nc")
            #ds = xr.open_dataset(
            #    "save.nc",
            #    chunks={"time": 1024},
            #)
            #first_variable_name = list(ds.variables)[4]
            #self.data = ds[first_variable_name]
```